# Why need click in save and continue to show images?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem with images of my products.

If I enter in the product XXXXX he have an image but don't show in the frontpage then I need enter in backend of Magento and click in Save an continue.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think this is enough information to pinpoint the problem. What have you tried? how do the images appear in the backend? How did the images end up in your backend (import, manual upload)?

Comment: I have an import process of products with all information about this. In backend i see in "Default Values" with "No select image" but if I enter in the differents website assigned to product have image. I only click in Save and continue edit in "Default values" and  appear the image in fronted

Comment: do you reindex the products after the import?

Comment: do indexing from admin and check it again.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments...
This is not enough info to pinpoint the problem.
But the fact that images show properly after saving the product and because the images are added via an import script makes me thing that the problem is that there is no reindex process started after the import.
try reindexing and see if the problem reproduces.

Comment: I'm reindexing, when finish it I told you the result

Comment: don't work the reindex. I found a script to re-save products. I told u when finish the script.